# Inconsistency in Place ID

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I'm using `GMSAutoCompletePrediction` results to then request further place details once a place has been selected by the user, as Google suggests.

Until very recently, this worked perfectly, but I have recently noticed different versions of PlaceID's being returned for `GMSAutoCompletePrediction` objects.

For example, a search for `Scotland` yields the first result `Scotland, United Kingdom`, with a Place ID of `ChIJn6HyA8TiYUgRFAfDCdj6weeaBhhTY290bGFuZCwgVW5pdGVkIEtpbmdkb20`.

Searching for the same place [here](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) yields the Place ID `ChIJn6HyA8TiYUgRFAfDCdj6wec`, which I also get from the place detail request.

As you can see, the two are similar, though the version returned from the autocomplete API is much longer, and does not (quite) contain the substring version of the smaller ID. Am I missing something here?

Comment: where do you search for first "scotland" ? In second search you give link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fix that was introduced in Places API autocomplete on December 22, 2016.

Please have a look at this bug in the public issue tracker and explanation in the comment #30:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11107#c30

The issue that many users experienced was that after cleanup of the data many duplicated place IDs were deleted and place autocomplete was changed to avoid zero_results for deleted places. So, this long place ID allows to resolve addresses or places even if the place ID was deleted to the correct short place ID.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, comments #38 and #39 tell you what to do with these now broken Place IDs if you have them stored: